# How to write application for simulating content form submission using cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Would like to ask for recommendation for ways that I can build application in cocoa to simulate user submission. For example, filling in registering form or even simulate a click in the web form. Not sure what exactly is the term for this.

Tried to google around, but didn't find any result. Closest I get is webkit, but not sure how to apply it and i thought it is only for web rendering.

Highly appreciated if someone could share some thoughts.

Comment: You mean a form on a web page?

Comment: ya. i mean form on the webpage, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

In short, you'll want to construct an HTTP POST with the appropriate form values in the body of the post.

You can use NSURLRequest or NSMutableURLRequest to construct the request.

Docs are at: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

or you can use something a bit higher level - I'm liking ASIHTTPRequest a lot right now.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: or if you are lazy (like I am) you could do a simple NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:someUrl]; and the url has something like http://www.foobar.com/index.php?value=1&anothervalue=2 though this would limit you to 100 characters.. :3